# Android Wear, connect to bluetooth device

Tags: android, bluetooth, wear-os

I want to connect a 3rd party bluetooth device to my Android Wear watch (Samsung Gear Live). I am trying to find documentation on how to do this but I am not having any luck. All the searches I do seem to think I want to attach to a phone.

Does anyone know of a good example that shows how to connect, for example, a bluetooth heart rate monitor (or other device) to the Android Wear so I can keep a history when the phone isn't present? Is this even possible? Would it be the same protocols as doing it from a phone/tablet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to connect 3rd party bluetooth devices to an Android Wear watch as you describe. You will need to pair your heart rate monitor with your phone, extract the data you want, and then use the Data Layer API to send the data to the wearable for display to the user.

EDIT: Android Wear devices now support the ability to pair with Bluetooth devices.

Comment: After digging around this is the same conclusion that I have come to. There are some articles that state a future version and API will make it possible but there doesn't seem to be a fixed timeline for delivery.

Comment: This blog post from the Engineering Director for Android Wear states that it will be possible to do bluetooth audio from Android Wear in the future, but that is all http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2014/09/android-wear-moving-forward-like.html

Comment: there are news about this question? I would like to connect an Android Wear via bluetooth RFCOMM /SPP to a bluetooth scanner. I am able to connect the scanner to a smartphone, but not to a wearable...

Comment: This is old. Modern watches connect with np

Answer (score 5):

@Ryan Tensmeyer, I think @Wayne Pieksarki's answer is now out-dated.  I was able to create and run a stand-alone app that used BLE to connect to a third-party bluetooth device, namely, a wireless thermometer.  I used a library called [SweetBlue](http://idevicesinc.com/sweetblue/) and tested the stand-alone app on an Android Wear Moto 360.  It worked great -- no phone required!

Comment: Can you please provide any reference link? The one which you have provided, in that SDK we have not found wearable connection support.

Comment: @steve Just download their sample apps and add their 10 lines of code (that demonstrate how to scan for, connect to a device, and perform reads and writes) into your wearable app.  Have you actually tried using it?