# Is it possible to send messages in background from Android wear?

Tags: android, wear-os

I have some questions about Android Wear

1. Is it possible to use a SIM Card in android wear(smart watch)?If possible, then which number is used to send the call?
2. Are we able to send text messages from Android wear to a specified mobile number in background?
3. Can we send messages from Android wear to mobile device without pairing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, at the moment none of the wearable devices running Android Wear support SIM cards.
2. Yes, you use `DataApi` or `MessageApi` to communicate with an app on the mobile device. The app on the mobile device would then send the text message.
3. No, you need to be paired to a device capable of sending text messages (so no tablets, unless the tablets are capable of sending text messages).

Answer (score 1):

1. Currently Android Wear does not support smart watches with mobile broadband / SIM card slots.
2. Yes, but only when a mobile phone is connected to the watch. Additionally you will have to create a mobile app which sends the SMS for you.
3. Unfortunately it is not possible to connect third party devices directly to an Android Wear watch. For more info [look here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26418182)

Answer (score 0):

Some previous answers are now outdated. The LG Watch Urbane LTE had a SIM Card slot. However, it was taken off the market by LG but can still be found on ebay. Also, an Android Wear Device equipped with WiFi can send messages without the need of a tethered phone. Instead, the Wear Device needs to be connected to a WiFi network and the phone must have some sort of data connection.