# Where can I find documentation on how Wear fundamentally communicates?

Tags: android, wear-os

Don't get me wrong, I know it's by bluetooth (or by Wifi for some supported watch).

I would like to understand how the communication works because I would like to be able to provide a third-party app for Android Wear to bring support for a Windows Phone or a BlackBerry phone.

I am looking for the basic stuffs, pairing and SMS alert.

Is there any documentation? I have done an app like that for Pebble and the Polar H7 sensor but can't figure out anything for Android Wear.

Thanks

Edit : I am not looking to build a wear application. Let's take for example that I want to build a Windows Phone app that pairs with the watch and is able to send SMS alert

Comment: Has Google actually locked down the BT stack in Wear? In most regards, a Wear device is just an Android device in a small package, and the *vast* majority of Android's APIs are still there, fully functional. Those that aren't are listed at http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/index.html - and BT isn't on that list. Have you tried to just access the BT interface directly?

Answer (score 1):

I recall someone making Wear work for iOS before Google oficially did. They posted it up on [Github](https://github.com/shiitakeo/android_wear_for_ios). It's a bit dated now, but it might help point you in the right direction.

Here's a link to the [BLEService class](https://github.com/shiitakeo/android_wear_for_ios/blob/master/wear/src/main/java/com/shiitakeo/android_wear_for_ios/BLEService.java). I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! It's a workaround that needs the watch to be paired with an Android device if I understand properly but definetely a room to some possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in [Android Wear, connect to bluetooth device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853858/android-wear-connect-to-bluetooth-device), it doesn't seem to be possible to connect Android Wear to any non-supported Bluetooth devices (e.g., non-Android or iOS phones) for now, or at least, there isn't any official documentation on how to do so. One user reported success pairing a standalone Wear app to a Bluetooth thermometer with a library called [SweetBlue](http://idevicesinc.com/sweetblue/), but I can't find anything on their site relating to Wear specifically.