# Wearable Bluetooth Connection

Tags: wear-os, android-bluetooth, ibeacon-android

Me and my friends are trying to make an Android Wear app that will communicate with Beacons. In our program, we have to set up a bluetooth connection between the wearable device and the beacon. We have not found any information, code examples, or anything else about Android Wear bluetooth connection. If you have any information, please tell me and help me end this struggle. Our wearable device is a Sony Smart Watch 3. Thank you for now.

Answer (score 0):

It was stated this would be supported as outlined in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853858/android-wear-connect-to-bluetooth-device) Stack Overflow question (points to Android Blog Post).

I would check out the Android API guide on [Bluetooth](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) and [BLE](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html). I  haven't developed BLE on Wear myself (have lots of other stuff), but I know a couple people who have and they said it works.

There isn't an official BLE on Wear doc though, so after you read the docs above, you might have to play around with it a little bit.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I have read all the android dev docs and try them also but these code do not work on wear and I could not find to translate to wear and I stuck. I searc google 15 pages with a lot of words and did came nothing. If you talk to your friends , they maybe tell me how to do it. Or if there is any chance to talk one of them to understand this situation to solve it. It would be very great. Thank you again.